# densities and isosceles triangles

Tags: probability

An isosceles triangle is formed by a unit vector in the x-direction and another in a random direction. Find the distribution of the length of the third side in three dimensions.

I know how to do this problem in two dimensions. The angle varies with uniform distribution, so after some trigonometry and calculation, you get (2/pi)arcsin(x/2). In three dimensions, the angle that varies is the angle between the random vector and the x-y plane. Then I'm stuck as to how the angle relates to the length of the third side (if at all).

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is the vector in the random direction a unit vector? If so, your distribution will depend on two angles...

Answer (score 3):

It might be useful to know the differential for area in spherical coordinates: $$d\Omega = \sin(\theta)\;d\theta\;d\phi$$
And recall that the total surface area of a sphere is $4\pi$.